# mapping images with gatsby-image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

trying to map images from a folder in a gatsby project. I set up the query in a way I thought would work based on guides I've seen. I do not get any errors and the site loads, but the images do not show up. Any thoughts? Thanks!

gatsby-config.js:

```
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
```

query:

```
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      query {
        allFile(filter:{extension:{regex:"/social/"}}) {
          edges {
            node {
              childImageSharp {
                fixed(width: 150, height: 150) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

    `)
```

return:

```
            <div className='socialPhotos'>
                {data.allFile.edges.map(node => 
                    <Img 
                      key={node.id}
                      title="Photo image"
                      alt="Photo"
                      fixed={node.childImageSharp.fixed}
                    />
                    )}
            </div>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

The filter in your graphQL query might be the problem. Did you try your query in graphiQL in the browser?

Because you define `images` in your `gatsby-config.js`, I would suggest filtering with `sourceInstanceName`:

```js
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      query {
      allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"}}) {
          edges {
            node {
              childImageSharp {
                fixed(width: 150, height: 150) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `)
```

Paste your query into GraphiQL in your browser and test if you get data back: `http://localhost:8000/___graphql`

### EDIT

This is how you can get one image from your query inside your component

```
const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const { data: { allFile: { edges } } } = props;
  const oneImage = edges.filter(
    el => el.node.childImageSharp.fixed.originalName === "yourImageFileName.png")
    [0].node.childImageSharp.fixed;
  // ...
```

Comment: I tried that query and I got an error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fixed' of undefined" for this line: ```fixed={node.childImageSharp.fixed}``` In the GraphiQL it gives me a stack of Unknown Fragments. Which is what I get for my other gatsby-image queries that do work. So maybe a start of a good thing there?

Comment: My apologies, I should have explained I am mapping through the images to display them all in a grid.